# Unable to run any services in cloudera manager express 5.9

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager, jvm-crash

Server Error
A server error has occurred. Send the following information to Cloudera.

Version: Cloudera Express 5.9.1 (#8 built by jenkins on 20170112-1158 git: a66d8bbdbe8bc3ee54235e55423f2f76c7d9f3b1)

```
Detected pause in JVM or host machine (e.g. a stop the world GC, or JVM not scheduled): paused approximately 2936ms: no GCs detected.

org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:Required String parameter 'action' is not present
at AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java line 738
in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker raiseMissingParameterException()
 Stack Trace:

AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java line 738
in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker raiseMissingParameterException()
HandlerMethodInvoker.java line 501
in org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker resolveRequestParam()
HandlerMethodInvoker.java line 340
in org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker resolveHandlerArguments()
HandlerMethodInvoker.java line 171
in org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker invokeHandlerMethod()
AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java line 436
in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter invokeHandlerMethod()
AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java line 424
in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter handle()
DispatcherServlet.java line 790
in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet doDispatch()
DispatcherServlet.java line 719
in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet doService()
FrameworkServlet.java line 669
in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet processRequest()
FrameworkServlet.java line 574
in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet doGet()
HttpServlet.java line 707
in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet service()
HttpServlet.java line 820
in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet service()
ServletHolder.java line 511
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder handle()
ServletHandler.java line 1221
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain doFilter()
UserAgentFilter.java line 78
in org.mortbay.servlet.UserAgentFilter doFilter()
GzipFilter.java line 131
in org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter doFilter()
ServletHandler.java line 1212
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain doFilter()
JAMonServletFilter.java line 48
in com.jamonapi.http.JAMonServletFilter doFilter()
ServletHandler.java line 1212
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain doFilter()
JavaMelodyFacade.java line 109
in com.cloudera.enterprise.JavaMelodyFacade$MonitoringFilter doFilter()
ServletHandler.java line 1212
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 311
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
FilterSecurityInterceptor.java line 116
in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor invoke()
FilterSecurityInterceptor.java line 83
in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
ExceptionTranslationFilter.java line 113
in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
SessionManagementFilter.java line 101
in org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java line 113
in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java line 146
in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java line 54
in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
RequestCacheAwareFilter.java line 45
in org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java line 182
in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
LogoutFilter.java line 105
in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java line 87
in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
ConcurrentSessionFilter.java line 125
in org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 323
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain doFilter()
FilterChainProxy.java line 173
in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter()
DelegatingFilterProxy.java line 237
in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy invokeDelegate()
DelegatingFilterProxy.java line 167
in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy doFilter()
ServletHandler.java line 1212
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain doFilter()
CharacterEncodingFilter.java line 88
in org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter doFilterInternal()
OncePerRequestFilter.java line 76
in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter doFilter()
ServletHandler.java line 1212
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain doFilter()
ServletHandler.java line 399
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler handle()
SecurityHandler.java line 216
in org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler handle()
SessionHandler.java line 182
in org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler handle()
SecurityHandler.java line 216
in org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler handle()
ContextHandler.java line 767
in org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler handle()
WebAppContext.java line 450
in org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext handle()
HandlerWrapper.java line 152
in org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper handle()
StatisticsHandler.java line 53
in org.mortbay.jetty.handler.StatisticsHandler handle()
HandlerWrapper.java line 152
in org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper handle()
Server.java line 326
in org.mortbay.jetty.Server handle()
HttpConnection.java line 542
in org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection handleRequest()
HttpConnection.java line 928
in org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler headerComplete()
HttpParser.java line 549
in org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser parseNext()
HttpParser.java line 212
in org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser parseAvailable()
HttpConnection.java line 404
in org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection handle()
SelectChannelEndPoint.java line 410
in org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint run()
QueuedThreadPool.java line 582
in org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message JVM pause points to the low heap size assigned to carry out its operations

`Detected pause in JVM or host machine (e.g. a stop the world GC, or JVM not scheduled): paused approximately 2936ms: no GCs detected.`

You should increase the CM server heap size. It can be set at CM server host in `/etc/default/cloudera-scm-server` change **-Xmx** option to a higher value preferably double the size. Save changes and restart Cloudera Manager.

Comment: The problem was with one of the python configuration file , that need to updated for cloudera 5.6+ managers.

Comment: There were no python related error message in the issue description so it could be that you still have a low heap while the issue caused due to the python error.